# Trying to pass dynamic value to Rundeck server. What is curl command format for [ data = '{"argString":"-servicename s.name() "}' ]

Tags: curl, python-requests, arguments, rundeck

Trying to pass dynamic value to Rundeck server. What is curl command format for `[ data = '{"argString":"-servicename s.name() "}' ] python`

```py
import os, psutil, 
import wmi, sys, requests

google=[ "Dnscache", "iphlpsvc","DPS","DsmSvc" ]
for redhat in google:
    s = psutil.win_service_get(redhat)
    if s.status() == 'running':
        print("service is running", s.name() )
    else:
        print("service is not running", s.name())
        headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token': 'API',
        }
        data = '{"argString":"-servicename s.name() "}'
        response = requests.post('http://IP:PORT/api/16/job/JOBID/executions', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Answer (score 1):

It works in the following way (three options in this case, with three string vars, `string1`, `string2` and `string3`):

```py
data = { "argString" : "-opt1 {} -opt2 {} -opt3 {}".format(string1, string2, string3)})
```

Check the [full](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63292123/10426011) example.

Comment: Variable(servicename) in rundeck, runningServer(sshd) I wanna to pass here to rundeck server.
```
import requests

runningServer=sshd

headers = {
 'Accept': 'application/json',
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token': 'API',
}
data = '{"argString":"-servicename runningService "}'
response = requests.post('http://IP:PORT/api/16/job/JOBID/executions', headers=headers, data=data)
```